# Stack and explode columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe to which I want to apply explode and stack at the same time. Explode the 'Attendees' column and assign the correct values to courses. For example, for Course 1 'intro to' the number of attendees was 24 but for Course 2 'advanced' the number of attendees was 46. In addition to that, I want all the course names in one column.

```
   import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'Session':['session1', 'session2','session3'],
                    'Course 1':['intro to','advanced','Cv'],
                    'Course 2':['Computer skill',np.nan,'Write cover letter'],
                    'Attendees':['24 & 46','23','30']})
```

If I apply the explode function to 'Attendees' I get the result

```
Course_df = Course_df.assign(Attendees=Course_df['Attendees'].str.split(' & ')).explode('Attendees')

    Session        Course 1 Course 2           Attendees
0   session1       intro to     Computer skill     24
0   session1       intro to     Computer skill     46
1   session2       advanced.    NaN                23
```

and when I apply the stack function

```
Course_df = (Course_df.set_index(['Session','Attendees']).stack().reset_index().rename({0:'Courses'}, axis = 1))
```

This is the result I get

```
  Session     level_1             Courses      Attendees
0  session1  Course 1            intro to        24
1  session1  Course 2      Computer skill        46
2  session2  Course 1            advanced        23
3  session3  Course 1                  Cv        30
```

Whereas the result I want is

```
   Session     level_1             Courses      Attendees
0  session1  Course 1            intro to        24
1  session1  Course 2      Computer skill        46
2  session2  Course 1            advanced        23
3  session3  Course 1                  Cv        30
4  session3  Course 2   Write cover letter        30
```

Comment: Is the index in your expected result arbitrary? If you actually are expecting this index, could you explain how you obtained it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A general Solution to your problem as far as I understood your problem would be to iterate over the attendees counts or the courses.
Here I loop over the attendees counts.
Therefore, I basically do the `explode` step manually and set all but the current/intended course to `pd.NA`.

With `df = Course_df`:

```py
df = df.assign(Attendees = df["Attendees"].str.split(" & "))

dfn = df.iloc[:0]  # Create empty dataframe with same columns as df

for didx, d in df.iterrows():

    # Explode manually
    for ci, attend_count in enumerate(d.Attendees):
        dfr = d.to_frame().T
        dfr.Attendees = attend_count

        # Set other courses than "Course <ci+1>" to NaN
        other_courses = [x for x in d.index if x.startswith("Course ") and x != f'Course {ci + 1}']
        # other_courses = d.index.to_series().filter(regex = f'Course [^{ci+1}]').index  # Alternative
        for c in other_courses:
            dfr[c] = pd.NA

        dfn = pd.concat([dfn, dfr])

dfn.set_index(["Session", "Attendees"]).stack().reset_index().rename({0: "Courses"}, axis = 1)
```

This returns:

```
    Session Attendees   level_2         Courses
0  session1        24  Course 1        intro to
1  session1        46  Course 2  Computer skill
2  session2        23  Course 1        advanced
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have market it as complete as it does answer the question asked. However, there are instances where two courses are held on the same day and the number of attendees are the same so they are not separated by '&' , how do I take care of such cases in this code?

Comment: Can you update your question with an example?

Comment: Hi, I have edited the data frame and results

Answer (score 0):

Melted df first

```
melted_df = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['Session', 'Attendees'], value_vars=['Course 1', 'Course 2'])
```

and then explode

```
result = melted_df.assign(Attendees=melted_df['Attendees'].str.split(' & ')).explode('Attendees')
```

Comment: This solution doesn't work. It just gives more or less the same answer I am still getting