# explode columns with multiple entries and then stack all columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have already asked this question in this link:

[Stack and explode columns in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75788847/stack-and-explode-columns-in-pandas)

And there is also an answer provided which works for the given dataset. However, it is possible that the two sessions occurring in a day has same number of attendees and thus they are not separated by '&'. In that case the algo ignores the 'Course 2'. For example, this is the dataset

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'Session':['session1', 'session2','session3'],
                    'Course 1':['intro to','advanced','Cv'],
                    'Course 2':['Computer skill',np.nan,'Write cover letter'],
                    'Attendees':['24 & 46','23','30']})
```

Now if I run the algorithm on this:

```
df = df.assign(Attendees = df["Attendees"].str.split(" & "))

dfn = df.iloc[:0]  # Create empty dataframe with same columns as df

for didx, d in df.iterrows():

    # Explode manually
    for ci, attend_count in enumerate(d.Attendees):
        dfr = d.to_frame().T
        dfr.Attendees = attend_count

        # Set other courses than "Course <ci+1>" to NaN
        other_courses = [x for x in d.index if x.startswith("Course ") and x != f'Course {ci + 1}']
        # other_courses = d.index.to_series().filter(regex = f'Course [^{ci+1}]').index  # Alternative
        for c in other_courses:
            dfr[c] = pd.NA

        dfn = pd.concat([dfn, dfr])

dfn.set_index(["Session", "Attendees"]).stack().reset_index().rename({0: "Courses"}, axis = 1)
```

It gives the output as

[image]

Although it should include 'write cover letter' session as well.
Desired output:

```
 Session     level_1             Courses      Attendees
0  session1  Course 1            intro to        24
1  session1  Course 2      Computer skill        46
2  session2  Course 1            advanced        23
3  session3  Course 1                  Cv        30
4  session3  Course 2  Write cover letter        30
```

Comment: Please write normal initial data (pd.DataFrame({...}). Yout have difference length of arrays

Comment: So sorry, I have fixed it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A pandas approach could be:

```
tmp = df.set_index('Session')
s = tmp.filter(like='Course').stack(dropna=False)

out = (pd.concat([s.rename('Courses'),
                  tmp['Attendees'].str.split(r'\s*&\s*', expand=True)
                    .stack(dropna=False).set_axis(s.index).rename('Attendees')
                  ], axis=1)
         .dropna(subset='Courses')
         .groupby(level='Session').ffill()
         .reset_index()
      )
```

Output:

```
    Session   level_1             Courses Attendees
0  session1  Course 1            intro to        24
1  session1  Course 2      Computer skill        46
2  session2  Course 1            advanced        23
3  session3  Course 1                  Cv        30
4  session3  Course 2  Write cover letter        30
```

Comment: It throws me an error 'TypeError: Index(...) must be called with a collection of some kind, 'Courses' was passed' also, will the solution work if we do not have the session name>

Comment: Does it raise the error with your provided DataFrame? if yes, please provide your python/pandas version, if no, please provide a reproducible example for which my code fails.

Comment: Yes, with my provided data frame. My pandas version is "pandas: 1.3.5" and Python version is "3.9.12.final.0"

Comment: I see, use `dropna(subset=['Courses'])` or update to a more recent pandas version. This works fine on the 1.5.3

Comment: It works thank you, can we not use session as index? I have other columns in the sheet as well that I want to include in the output

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer, not optimized:

```
new_df_list = []
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    splited = row['Attendees'].split(r'\s*&\s*')
    for _ in splited:
        new_df_list.append(pd.DataFrame({k: [v] for k,v in {**row, 'Attendees': _.strip()}.items() if k!='index'}))       
new_df = pd.concat(new_df_list)
new_df.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

Optimized version:

```
fields, split_field = [x for x in df.columns if x != 'Attendees'], 'Attendees'
new_df = pd.concat((df[split_field].str.split(r'\s*&\s*', expand=True), df[fields]), axis=1). \
    melt(id_vars=fields, value_name=split_field). \
    dropna(subset=[split_field])[[*fields, split_field]]
```

Comment: I want one single column of courses and their respective attendees. I have included the desired output as well